# can eth_call() make this?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, bsc, cpp-ethereum, ethereum-classic

I have a contract and inside the contract there is a non-payable function that can call externally. this function do some analysis,and calls other payable function than can make real transaction using the contract balance(like transfer,swap). So if i call the first function using eth_call(), can the inside function make real transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If there's no transaction signed by a private key being broadcasted and gas paid, the chains state won't change, no matter what.

Comment: if i send raw transaction and if no state is changed, does still burns gas? like if reads state and finishes the excution, does still costs gas?

Comment: @BirukDamte If it's done through eth_sendtransaction or sendrawtransaction, yes. There's absolutely no point in doing that though

Comment: lets say my function reads state of the chain and decides to do no transaction and finishes the execution because some conditions aren't meet. Does this costs gas? I want to execute both the decision part and the transaction part in one call.

Comment: Yes. Take the descision off chain instead. @BirukDamte

Comment: getting state of the block chain, making decision off chain and sending new raw transaction is  very time costy for me. Because I'm trying to arbitrage. Any suggestion please?